# apollo graphQL - how to send array of object in mutation by angular

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

i want to send an array of objects in graphQL , but when i send an array i got an error bad request that

```js
 createGift(gift, categoryid, url, banner,occasionid) {
    let connectQuery='';
    for (var i = 0; i < occasionid.length; i++) 
    {connectQuery+=`{"id":"${occasionid[i]}"}`}
console.log(connectQuery)
    return this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation : this.mutation,
       variables: {
        "input": {
             "name": `${gift.name}`,
             "description": `${gift.description}`, 
             "imageIcon": `${url}`,
             "price": `${gift.price}`,
             "category":{
                  "connect":{"id": `${categoryid}`}
                  },
              "occasions":{
                  "connect":`[${connectQuery}]`
              }, 
              "banners":  {
                  "set": banner}  
         }         
      }

    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

is there a way to send it ?

Comment: you should check your `Server` to see if it supports an array first! otherwise, you should call the mutation in a for loop!